# AS3 How to Reset A Tween on MouseOut of target mc?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, gsap

In this example I have 3 panels, inside a mc called "panelHolder".

Goal: To be able to have only the bgr color in the "bgr" mc (panelHolder.panel1.Bgr) tweened to a different color when the mouse is over the target mc expanding, and then reset when the mouse is over one of the other target mcs (which should also run that same animation)?

Here is my code:

```
import com.greensock.*; 
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import com.greensock.plugins.*;
```

//Setting initial state

```
panelHolder.panel1.alpha = 0;
panelHolder.panel2.alpha = 0;
panelHolder.panel3.alpha = 0;
```

//Initiating start animation

```
function init():void {
TweenLite.to(panelHolder.panel1, .5, {y:266, alpha:1, delay:0.4});
TweenLite.to(panelHolder.panel2, .5, {y:400, alpha:1, delay:0.6});
TweenLite.to(panelHolder.panel3, .5, {y:534, alpha:1, delay:0.8});
}

init();

panelHolder.panel1.props = {ty:266, by:516, ind:1};
panelHolder.panel2.props = {ty:400, by:650, ind:2};
panelHolder.panel3.props = {ty:534, by:784, ind:3};

panelHolder.panel1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onMouseOver);
panelHolder.panel2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onMouseOver);
panelHolder.panel3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onMouseOver);

function onMouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void
{
var mousedOver:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target);
for(var i:int=0; i<panelHolder.numChildren; i++)
{
     var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(panelHolder.getChildAt(i));


if(mc.props.ind <= mousedOver.props.ind)
```

{

```
TweenLite.to(mc, .5, {y:mc.props.ty});
}
```

//if not animate to the bottom

```
else {
TweenLite.to(mc, .5, {y:mc.props.by});
}
}
}
stop();
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: You code seems right to me. Is there a problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add a color Tween to the tab area I did this:
Inside the onMouseOver function I added the following:
This will animate the background tab color:

```
TweenMax.to(mousedOver.tab.bgrColor, .5, {colorTransform:{tint:0x2ea0dd, tintAmount:1}});
```

and then in an if else statement to reset:

```
if(mc.props.ind != mousedOver.props.ind ){
    TweenMax.to(mc.tab.bgrColor, .5, {colorTransform:{tint:0x2ea0dd, tintAmount:0}});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you just want to do your color tweens in the if/else.

```
if(mc.props.ind <= mousedOver.props.ind)
{
    TweenLite.to(mc, .5, {y:mc.props.ty});
    TweenMax.to(mc, 1, {colorTransform:{tint:0x2ea0dd, tintAmount:1}}); 
{
else
}
    TweenLite.to(mc, .5, {y:mc.props.by});
    TweenMax.to(mc, 1, {colorTransform:{tint:0x2ea0dd, tintAmount:0}}); 
}
```

Comment: "To access" what exactly?

Comment: Thanks Adam, yes that's what I tried already, but I actually need to access the "Bgr" movieclip as in `panel1.tab1.Bgr` for example, as I only would like to change the color property of the mc "Bgr" within panel1.tab1 (as well as the other panels).

The above code tweens the entire mc.

Also, I would like to tween all 3 "Bgr" mcs of the panels.

Ideally I would like to use an array to run the tween color function for the 3 panels and then a second function that does the resetting in AS3.

Please advise.